# Something missing from Sitecore package, how to find out what it is

Tags: sxa, solr, packages

I've been trying to hand off some content for our developers to test with. However, when they use the installation wizard to install my package, the installation fails. I checked their logs and am seeing this message:

```
ManagedPoolThread #12 16:16:04 ERROR One or more exceptions occurred while processing the subscribers to the 'packageinstall:items:ended' event.
Exception[1]: System.NullReferenceException 
Message[1]: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
Source[1]: Sitecore.ContentSearch 
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler.IsExcludedFromIndex(SitecoreIndexableItem indexable, Boolean checkLocation)
   at Sitecore.XA.Foundation.VersionSpecific.Search.SxaItemCrawler.IsExcludedFromIndex(SitecoreIndexableItem indexable, Boolean checkLocation)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler.GetContextIndexRanking(IIndexable indexable)
...
...
```

I found another post on here that would seem to indicate there's a missing item in my package that's causing the Solr index re-population to fail, but I don't know what it is. I've checked the package project over and over, I believe I've included everything. How can I find out what item is missing?

FYI, we all have Sitecore 9.1 with SXA 1.8 installed. The content is SXA based content.

Comment: Looks like there is something wrong with the SXA installation on the client which trying to install the package?

Comment: Seems to be the similar issue discussed in this post https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/509/installing-package-acting-different-between-2-environments  Try the same, compare the config files from your machine and your developers, if you have any new search index linked with your new package then disable that, install the package and then enable the index..

Comment: I had this same issue and it was due to the SXA indexes not being set up.